# how to do search in CheckListBox

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets, wxformbuilder

I want to create a customized dialog like Excel filter [fucntion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJphH.png).

when search bar change then below checklistbox will update, and checklistbox can be multiple selection.

And now I have create a [dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0koh.png), expected when wx.SearchCtrl change, then update below checklistbox, but I can't found how to do that.

Please give me a hand.

```
class MyFrame1 (wx.Dialog):
    
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, -1)
        lst = ['apple','box','cat','dog','eye']
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.search = wx.SearchCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.message = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Pick some fruit")
        self.clb = wx.CheckListBox(self, -1, choices = lst)
        self.chbox = wx.CheckBox(self, -1, 'Select all')
        self.btns = self.CreateSeparatedButtonSizer(wx.OK | wx.CANCEL)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.EvtChBox, self.chbox)
        sizer.Add(self.message, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)
        sizer.Add(self.search, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )
        sizer.Add(self.clb, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)
        sizer.Add(self.chbox, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)
        sizer.Add(self.btns, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def EvtChBox(self, event):
        state = self.chbox.IsChecked()
        for i in range(self.clb.GetCount()):
            self.clb.Check(i, state)

    def OnExit(self, event):
        self.Close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App() 
    frm = MyFrame1(None) 
    frm.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: The SearchCtrl is nothing more than a search button, a text control, and a cancel button. What you use those for is down to your ingenuity. Decide what those CheckBoxes will effect then build the command/search you wish to perform based on the text entered, taking the results of the checkboxes into consideration. For example: if you entered `ls` into the text and selected `apple` and `cat` you could build a command to search for all files with names starting with apple or cat.

Comment: Thank your reply, I have fixed the issus.